# shell script to monitor a "word" in log, then kill and restart process

Tags: python, linux, shell

I'm new into script/linux. I've been doing some research for it but now I'm stuck.

I run a python script wich after sometime I got an error (displays in the terminal window).

I need to:
1. put the displayed content into a log or txt file,
2. monitor that file, and when the word "331" appears then:
3. kill the script.py process
4. restart it (keep this a loop, so it will kill and restart the script.py everytime it gives the "331" error.

In my ignorance I did this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#execute the python script as a normal user and make a output.txt file so the grep command can find the "331" word

echo "Starting Script"
python main.py | tee output.txt

#using tail and grep to look for the "331" word:
if [ tail -f /path/to/script/output.txt | grep "331" ]; then
    echo "Error found. Killing Process"
    killall main.py
    echo "Restarting script..."
    ./startcap2.sh
fi
done
```

It starts the script, but fails to kill/restart if the erros appears.

What am I missing?

thanks for help!

Comment: Where's your loop? `tail -f` will never quit, so the script is stuck there anyways. And `killall main.py` won't work because the process will be called `python` — `killall python` is probably not a good idea though. Oh, and the script will hang on `python main.py` anyways, since it's running in the foreground. Maybe try just executing `tail -f ... | grep "331" | head -n 1`, that should pause until it finds such a line in the log.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: So just changing the tail command for the one you suggested may work? Do I need to run the python script on background? If so, how could I do it? I'm very new to *nix and scripting so, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I would suggest trying my answer first, but: Running the python script in background: `python main.py &`. Changing the command may work, but you'll still need a loop, and you won't need the condition.

Comment: OK, what about running the python main.py | tee output.txt ? Should be python main.py & | tee output.txt to make it run in the background?

Comment: `python main.py | tee output.txt &` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you just grep the process itself, and use `head -n 1` it should get killed due to the broken pipe automatically:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting Script"
while true
do
python main.py | tee -a output.txt | grep "331" | head -n 1 # run until first line with 331 occurs
echo "Restarting script..."
done
```

Comment: Just a question: Is it possible to use the "until" loop to monitor the commnad output status (0 or 1) and restart the script when the output value is different from 0?

Comment: You mean the return value of the program? Sure. That's in `$?`.